# UDP tracker byte order flipping depending on response status

Tags: python, sockets, udp, bittorrent, endianness

I am trying to write a bittorrent client in python (for my own education). My code is working to send requests to UDP trackers, but I am getting strange responses back that are not making sense to me. I used `tcpdump` to take a look at the raw packets and it seems that the tracker is changing the byte order of its responses. Sometimes they seem to be in big endian order (which is what I expected) but the error responses seem to be partially in little endian order. I know this sounds crazy so I suspect I must be missing something, but I can't for the life of my figure out what.

Here is a good response:

```
11:57:50.676956 IP 31.172.63.252.80 > 192.168.1.4.52404: UDP, length 20
    0x0000:  4500 0030 0000 4000 3011 2969 1fac 3ffc  E..0..@.0.)i..?.
    0x0010:  c0a8 0104 0050 ccb4 001c bf4e 0000 0002  .....P.....N....
    0x0020:  2134 0ba3 0000 1ebf 0000 000a 0000 066c  !4.............l
```

You can see at the end of the third line, the `action` field is equal to `000 0002` which is the expected "scrape/success" value in big endian order as expected per the protocol.

Here is where things get weird:

```
11:58:22.913378 IP 31.172.63.253.80 > 192.168.1.4.46346: UDP, length 33
    0x0000:  4500 003d 0000 4000 3011 295b 1fac 3ffd  E..=..@.0.)[..?.
    0x0010:  c0a8 0104 0050 b50a 0029 1536 0300 0000  .....P...).6....
    0x0020:  b4c0 d1a2 436f 6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e 2049  ....Connection.I
    0x0030:  4420 6d69 7373 6d61 7463 682e 00         D.missmatch..
```

This seems to be an error message, and per the protocol spec, the `action` field should have the value `3`, which in big endian order should be `0000 0003`. But this response instead is giving me `0300 0000` which is `3` in little endian order.

This boggles my mind and I am hoping someone wiser than me can help me figure out what is going on.

EDIT: And these are the two sites I have been using for reference: The [official docs](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html) and then [another site](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html) which is referenced by the docs.

Comment: I agree with you. Looking at the packet there seems to be a bug in the tracker response. Given the IPs you connected to I see that the trackers you used was tracker. openbittorrent.com/publicbt.com/istole.it. They and most of all other open public trackers is using [OpenTracker](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/).